# Consequences of turning off session.cookie_secure in PHP

Tags: php, security

What are the security risks associated with turning off "session.cookie_secure" in PHP under secure connections? I'm itching to turn this off since I'm unable to access session data from https pages to http pages.

Comment: Why pay for an SSL cert if you're going to bypass part of the security?  If you **don't** have an SSL cert, how/why are you mucking around on https?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a login system for a shopping cart. I need the checkout and login pages to be delivered via https and the rest via http. I'm having difficulty propagating session data across the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The risk is that the cookie data is transfered over plain HTTP.  Anyone sniffing packets on the network would be able to view the data in the cookie.  Then, they can pretend to be you ([Session Fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation)).

Now, some would argue that if someone can sniff packets on the network, that they are in a position to execute a [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack so it's not a huge deal.  However this is not 100% correct.  Look at what happened with Google.  They were able to sniff raw WIFI traffic without actually compromising the network (which would be required for a MITM attack).  Sending cookies over HTTP can open up [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) attacks where if you kept them to HTTPS only they would not be.

If you need access to be secure, keep secure_only set.  If you don't care about the data (or use multiple-factors, or want to risk it), then open it up...

One potential workaround is to use a custom error handler, and set 2 session identifiers (one is secure_only).  Then you can "log in" via both, yet require the secure one for anything important (Such as accessing important data.  This would require some work to do correctly, but could be a decent solution to the problem...

Comment: Actually you are mistaken about session fixation, session.use_only_cookies takes care of that.

Comment: @Rook: Session IDs passed via URLs are not the only form of fixation.  They are the most common since they are the easiest to detect and execute, but if you can sniff the packets from someone using an unsecured WIFI (for example) you can also fixate on their cookie.  Sure, it's harder, but it's not unrealistically hard. (And I agree 100% that site should be using `use_only_cookies`)...

Comment: @ircmaxell session fixation is the other way around.  The hacker creates the session id as an unauthenticated user and then tricks the victim into authenticating the session.  This can be done by getting them to click on a link if session id's can be passed as GET or POST.  Then the attacker already knows the session id and then can check if the user made it authenticated.  Sniffing for a cookie is a OWASP A9 violation.

Comment: @ircmaxell cool.  yeah that is a tricky one i mistook that one for a while too.   Its not a very obvious or common attack.  (also +1,  this is a good answer)

Comment: @ircmaxell I'm not sure if I have the time to implement your suggestion above. However, now I'm thinking of just delivering everything via HTTPS once the user has visited a page on a secure connection.

Comment: @Dave: that is indeed the best way of doing it as it removes the possibility of you screwing something up... :-D