# session_start() works only on Chrome

Tags: php, session

I met very strange problem.

I have two simple php files:
testSession1.php:

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = "Test here...";
?>
<a href="testSession2.php">Next</a>
```

testSession2.php:

```
<?
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

In Chrome i get the expected result:

```
Array ( [test] => Test here... )
```

but in Mozilla and IE i get only:

```
Array()
```

Note that cookies are fully enabled on all the browsers i use. I'm so confused...
Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I did the trick using

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600, "/", "localhost", false, false);
```

So it is something with my php.ini, vhosts or .htaccess config

Unfortunately IE continue to deny setting sessions :(

Comment: I haven't experienced this behavior before but... Does the cookie get generated in FF? If you manually create a cookie in FF with the one from Chromes value does it display?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Which create the cookie or check that one is generated?

Comment: Actually this behavior started since last FF update.

Comment: In FF open firebug, go to the `Cookies` tab. In Chrome open the `developer console` then go to resources then Cookies.

Comment: Really odd as i have never heard of or experienced something like this either. You could try to clear the php session storage location, maybe clear the cache in firefox too?

Comment: would clear all domain cookies and test again

Comment: i'm using localhost. Cookies are created on both Mozilla and Chrome with similar settings (only sessid is different). I noticed that Mozilla is with security flag.

Comment: does not work on FF or Chrome on my local, `<? session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?> ` `<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>` works on both FF and chrome. PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11.

Comment: #madamia - same result :(

Comment: I have had issues with sessions not storing / session id being renewed on refresh. It was down to incorrect php_value session.referer_check and php_value session.cookie_domain values in a vhost configuration. Are you sending any headers? Compare the headers on firefox and chrome.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Could be a local storage issue. Also as suggested, destroy the session and try again.

Comment: @bksi I pressed enter before finishing my comment.

Comment: @mdamia that is a setting that the OP has enabled. Depends on each deployment. It is called short tags.

Comment: i did the trick using session_set_cookie_params(3600, "/", "localhost", false, false);

Comment: @Chris85, ph crap. I have to enable my php short-tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Here is what i found out:

Using:

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600, "/", "localhost", false, false);
```

i did the trick, so i suspected php.ini for missconfiguration.

after change these settings in my php.ini:

```
session.save_path = "c:/temp"
session.cookie_secure = 0
session.cookie_httponly = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 3600
```

After restarted my apache, it works now on all the browsers.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You deserve to mark yourself as the answer in this case , go ahead, well done! :)

Comment: hi please note that making `cookie_secure` off will pose a security issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993799/consequences-of-turning-off-session-cookie-secure-in-php

Comment: I just showed what worked in this situation. It seems FF has trouble to handle this setting.