# PHP starting a new session on every page

Tags: php, session, wamp

I am trying to use a session value that set is on one page and called on another. The problem is when I call the session value on the other page it says that the value does not exist, specifically undefined index. I think that PHP is starting a new session with every page. I have checked the following things:

Folder `exists(tmp)`, is accessible, and is writable. Checked using `attrib`.

`Session_start` is in both pages as the first line of each page.

Tried to run the page using PHP 5.6.40, 7.0, and 7.3.5 (WAMP Server). I have the same issue across all versions.

`php.ini` settings are set to default so it would be logical that you should be able to access sessions with the default settings.

I can access the session file in the tmp folder and observe that it is saving the variable to the text file itself.

Code(check page):

```
     <?php
     session_start();
     ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     ...
     <script>
     function submitcheck(){
       var x,y,text,text1;
       x=document.getElementById('checkv').value;
       y=<?php echo $_SESSION['code'];?>;
       if(x==y){
       ...
```

Code(intermediary page):

```
    <?php
    session_start();
       ...
    function __construct(){
        $this->number=random_int(1,999999);
        ...
        $_SESSION['code']=$this->number;
    }
    ...
    ?>
```

What I don't understand is why PHP is starting a new session on every page and not accessing the one that is currently there.

Comment: `Folder exists(tmp),` what exactly this means? Exists where? Is this relative path? If so are you sure it really points where you thing it does?

Comment: It means that the folder does actually exist and I can navigate to it in the file system in a command prompt or File explorer. . It exists at "c:/wamp64/tmp". I would think this would be an absolute path and not a relative path.

Comment: Check this, it my help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173172/session-start-works-only-on-chrome